# Position a label on top of an input

Tags: html, css

I'm having this problem where I need to place a **Label** on top of an input element. The below image uses background images to do the trick but I want to do it with a label. Or a span maybe! I tried with may google links where CSS3 styling tutorials but found nothing. All of them are using images to place icons. I want to place a span/label with text in it.

[image: Sample input element.]

As in the above image How can I place a span or a label in the way the icon is positioned. any ideas.

Comment: You already asked that question, besides there alot of response on that, too bad i cant donvote you, or close as duplicate.

Comment: I've asked this but no one has understood the question! I'm marking that question delete!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p9SA2/)

```
<div>
    <label for="test">L</label>
    <input type="text" id="test" />
</div>

div {
    position: relative;
}

label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
}

input[type=text] {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```